# My Gitlab CI/CD pipeline failing in cache with FATAL: file does not exist error

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

right now I'm trying to learn CI/CD with Gradle. I'm using GitLab CI's pipeline. With a Gitlab documentation and a little bit search found gilab-ci.yml like this

```
image: gradle:jdk11

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME='pwd'/.gradle

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches

package:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew check
```

However its not working for my Spring boot application
Gitlab pipline gives me "FATAL: file does not exist" error. I'm thinking its due to caching but everything seems okay in YAML file

Comment: Which step the pipeline is failing ???

Comment: i think in "Restoring Cache"

Comment: Restoring cache
00:01
Checking cache for default...
FATAL: file does not exist

Comment: Can you add a larger excerpt of the job log instead of just the error message?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dhJw1p6 this is the full job log

Answer (score 16):

Even though "FATAL: file does not exist" is red and bold, it is not failing the build but is just a warning. The actual cause of the failure is a couple of lines below: `/bin/bash: line 104: ./gradlew: Permission denied`.

To resolve the issue, update the build stage with the following code segment:

```
package:
 stage: build
 script:
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  - ./gradlew --build-cache assemble
```